# Flutter: How can I persist a ReorderableListView?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I understand how I can create a ReorderableListView. However, I can't find the answer to a very simple question: how can I persist the changed order of the items between sessions? (My app uses a sqflite database.)

Comment: save the array then. Use that array when your app starts